# Emacs, cedet and c++/c++11 support

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, emacs

I usually develop using emacs in a linux environment (ubuntu) because I love the editor. I've been also using eclipse from time to time but I find it slow.

Since I want IDE-like features, I tried to setup cedet and it seems to be sort of doing the work.

1. I find that cedet never finds base class members. For example, `std::vector` in gcc has `std::vector::size` in its base class and it cannot find it.
2. Seems inaccurate: If I do something like "`myvector.`" it will give me completions like `size_type`.
3. Cannot use `auto` from c++11, it seems not to work.
4. srecode-getset gives me errors even for basic usage.

My configuration does not give any error and is based in [alexott cedet config](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-cedet.el).

My questions are:

1. The completion is that inaccurate still? (Think of "`vector.`" giving things like "`size_type`".
2. What is the status of cedet for c++/c++11? Should auto be working? I'm doing anything wrong?

I tried to use both bundled ubuntu version and last version from bzr repository. CEDET seems an extremely useful tool, but I wonder if it needs more work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although it can do lots of things, CEDET still needs a lot of work, especially for C++, as
it's just one of the languages that it supports, probably the most complex one. It would be great
if people with knowledge of bison and elisp contributed more.

Comment: I don't know bison, unfortunately :-( But with a bit more accuracy this would be really great.

Comment: I develop `https://github.com/abo-abo/function-args`
that makes use of CEDET.
I'd love to have support for C++ default function arguments, but
this hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: afaik creating a C++ grammar using BNF like bison will take is an unsolved problem - even with the GLR parser. just something to think about...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on CEDET for completion, you might want to consider an alternative completion provider in Emacs.

Auto-complete-clang and auto-complete-clang-async both work with clang to get completions and with the auto-complete package to display them. Company-clang is similar, but uses the company package to display completions.

There is another minor mode for C, C++, and ObjC called [irony](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode) that uses clang to get completions and can use multiple front-ends to display completions. This might have the best documentation for getting it set up.

All of these are available on [Marmalade](http://marmalade-repo.org/) for use with the package manager in Emacs 24.

Comment: CLang and LLVM are not "Free" as in free speech. They may matter some.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this may be a less-than-sufficient answer (and I'd prefer to mention this in the comments but I'm shy on points), but there is an Eclipse plugin for emacs functionality called emacs+. This [**link**](http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus/update-site) should be friendly to your Eclipse install manager (on Indigo I can copy and paste it into Help->Install New Software->Work With). Because Eclipse was otherwise attractive to you and therefore this can indirectly alleviate your problem...

Comment: Well, I tried before but it's not nearly emacs, unfortunately. Just a few combinations, but not the true feeling of not moving your hands to the mouse, which is a big point for me.

Comment: There are MANY editor choices that work without moving your hands to the mouse.  Each has its own clumsinesses and features.  Personally, I consider any editor that does not support block marking (as opposed to string marking) an abomination.  vi, Kedit, X2, THE, SlickEdit, etc.  I even got eclipse to be mostly mouse free.

Answer (score 0):

`size_type` is actually a member type of `vector`, so that's not as crazy as it sounds.  Of course, the syntax is `myvector::size_type`, not with a period.